# Java EE web applications and environment configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

Hello stackoverflow Users,

I have found myself working on a Java EE Web Application and I know for a fact that my application is going to be deployed into multiple environments. Each environment may have slightly different configuration of some features, e.g. remote web-service URLs. Additionaly, I would like - if possible - to have the following 2 properties met:

1. Per environment config should not in web-application repository

   This is because I feel it does not belong there. I would not want to manage n-configurations next to my source code. Moreover, if there are secrets there, I would not want every developer to see them...
2. Enforce completeness of configuration

   If I say that I need a certain configuration parameter/resource then it would be meaningless if it was not provided. I would not want my application to start in such case.

Please, can somebody more knowledgable and experienced help me and nudge me into the right direction?

---

### My findings so far

Naturally, I have spent some time searching the answer already ...

**Spring framework**

I know that spring provides an [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) class as an abstraction of environment-specific configuration. However, I am not using Spring framework, nor does it describe how to put this configuration outside of the web applicatoin.

**Java EE JNDI Service**

According to the [Java EE platform specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_ee-8-final-eval-spec/index.html), the right way to do it would be to use `env-entry`, `resource-ref` and `resource-env-ref` elements in my `WEB-INF/web.xml` and have them bound/set to values in the web app container configuration.

This actually sounds very good, except that I don't know how to enforce the completeness of this configuration. I mean, I declare the above mentioned elements, to tell the deployer that I need them, yet I see (tested on tomcat) that application still deploys (and works incorrectly) when some, say resource-env-ref, is not bound.

I don't know how to achieve it tbh, however, if there is nothing better, it still feels like the best thing I could find. :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the JDNI approach.

I have added validation of configuration by introducing a custom `ServletContextListener` implementation.